# Load Entity in Microsoft Dynamics via Web API (passing in a phone number)

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to figure out how to load an "entity" (contact, customer etc.) in Microsoft Dynamics by passing in a phone number via the web API (meaning as a URL parameter). If there is a match for the phone number against any of the records, then the record is loaded in Dynamics (browser).

I'm digging through the web API documentation, but so far I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I'd like to know why the question alone gets "-2"....

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this assuming that you are asking about Dynamics CRM.

The process can be divided into two steps:

1. Fetch the GUID of the record in CRM (if it exists) based on the phone number.
2. Use the GUID to open the record in CRM.

For simplicity I will answer this for fetching and showing only one type of record (in this case a Contact). It should easily expand to multiple records.

**Step 1:**

As you mention in the title, the Web API/[ODATA endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461(v=crm.7).aspx) can be queried for data. The following sample query fetches the GUID of the record with a phone number equal to 12345678:

```
https://yourorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=ContactId&$filter=Telephone1 eq '12345678'
```

**Step 2:**

Use the GUID fetched in Step 1 (if a record exists) to [open the Contact form with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx). The record will open directly in CRM by inserting the GUID in the following:

```
https://yourorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7BGUIDhere%7D
```

As mentioned you can expand this process to query for different entity types and open the corresponding forms.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for !...thank you !